# WMI Queries in C?

Tags: c, wmi

Is it possible to issue WMI WQL queries in plain C? And if yes, how?

Comment: As a C# programmer I have a hard time finding C library documentation. WMI is exposed by System.Management in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any programming language that you want as long as you can call into the [COM API for WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389276(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Not sure if this has changed since this answer was made but the page currently states **WMI only supports C++ development using Microsoft Visual C++ version 6.0 and later development systems**.

Comment: @MikeKwan: If you can't call the COM API for WMI from C, I guess you could write a dll in C++ that wraps the calls to the WMI API.  The dll would then export a set of functions that you could call from C.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can do this sort of thing by using ExecQuery(), though this example is in C++.  BTW this guy couldn't get it to work, but you may check out what he's doing.

Hope this helps.

http://forums.devshed.com/c-programming-42/wmi-wql-querying-problem-in-c-215026.html

More WMI programming:

http://www.vedivi.com/blog/2008/05/how-to-enable-remote-desktop-programmatically/